# Run Batch-file Elevated through Windows Terminal

Tags: batch-file, elevated-privileges, windows-terminal

> Get Elevated .Bat File through Windows Terminal

This script succesfully start .ps1 file elevated through Windows Terminal

```
$Admin = (fltmc).count -eq 11
$arg = "-d `"$PSScriptRoot`" -p `"Windows PowerShell`"", "cmd /c powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File `"$PSCommandPath`""
if ( !$Admin ) { Start -Verb RunAs -FilePath "wt.exe" -ArgumentList $arg; taskkill /f /im $PID; exit }

if ( $Admin ) { 'Running with Admin privilages' } else { 'Required Admin privilages' }
Pause
```

Does anyone know how to run bat file with admin privilege through Windows Terminal?

This code get elevated in cmd.exe it self, not in/ through windows terminal

```
@echo off 
Net session >nul 2>&1 || (PowerShell start -verb runas '%~0' &exit /b)
Echo Administrative privileges have been got. & pause
```

[image: cmd elevated]

I want the batch file opened in windows terminal like screenshoot below:

[image: wt.exe]

Comment: "fail" how? We are here to help you to fix a single specific problem with your code, not to "edit" it for you. If you do not tell us what is happening and what is supposed to happen, and include all output, errors and debugging, your question will probably be closed.

Comment: Please read the [tour] and [mcve] and [ask]

Comment: `cmd` is the interpreter that actually runs things; Terminal is just how you interact with it. In that screenshot, you're actually interacting with `cmd` via conhost. Based on this, my best guess is that you're asking how to have scripts start in Terminal by default. In the Settings tab in Terminal, and under Startup, change "Default terminal application" to Terminal.

Comment: wt.exe was set as default. in normal user, all console opened in wt.exe, but when get-elevated, different. batch file opened in cmd.exe, not wt.exe like the picture @SomethingDark

Answer (score -1):

Terminal is a "virtual machine" to run CMD, in reality, you're actually using CMD and its processes (see image below) with the key difference being the ability to handle some special characters (for example, emojis).

So there is no need to care about whether your script runs in Terminal or CMD, it's all the same (except if you like how Terminal looks, or, if you use special characters)

[image: Terminal using CMD processes]

Comment: Yes. Prefer run in Terminal because it's Looks and features

Comment: Windows Terminal is a **terminal**, exactly like conhost.exe used by older Windows. cmd, powershell, bash, zsh... and the likes are **shells** which must attach to some terminal to run. Cmd never runs alone and it's better to use a better terminal like Windows Terminal. **It's not a "virtual machine" at all** (which is things like NTVDM for 16-bit apps). See [What is the difference between shell, console, and terminal?](https://superuser.com/q/144666/241386)

Comment: @phuclv buddy, that post you sent there is 13 years old. Terminal isn't even 5 years old. Moreover, it's talking about **LINUX** terminal, not **WINDOWS** terminal (those are two whole different things). Also, the reason why I double-quote "virtual machine" is because it's not to be understood by its real meaning. Open **Windows** Terminal and run `taskkill [/f] /im cmd.exe` to kill every Command Prompt task. Terminal will then inform you with "process exited.....", because, **Terminal uses Command Prompt.**

Comment: @ItsSuperPlayz that link explains the **concept** of terminal and shell, which are still the same for 50 years, for all OSes. "Windows Terminal" (**not** Terminal) is just one new app that act as the terminal, just like xterm, cmder... on Windows. Windows Terminal obviously can run any shells like bash, zsh, cmd, powershell like any other terminals. It's not related to cmd in anyway. It's just that you're running cmd by default in your environment